# Query update multiple rows

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have table with token, userName, StatusId. Before i insert any row in table for a specific user i would like to check if any rows with active status are there if so update it to inactive.

I am unable to figure out how can i do this in LINQ. Currently iam retreving my values as the query below.

```
var activeUsers = 
   (from _users in currentDataContext.Users 
        where _users.StatusId.Equals(1) 
        select _session);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
users = currentDataContext.Users.Where(o => o.StatusId == 1);
foreach(var item in users)
  item.StatusId = 0;
currentDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Beware that If you app is multi user then there is a chance that DB has been changed after you queried the database.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The status id value is in a look up table with name StatusType with columns statusid and statusdesc. How can i link this in the query directly. For instance where user.statusid=statustype.statusid.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```cs
currentDataContext.Users.Where(x=> x.StatusId == true).First().StatusId = False;
currentDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Note, will throw an exception if there's no matching record with `StatusId==true`